# solr wont work with jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, solr

When I enter 'http://localhost:8983/solr/select/?q=body:hello` in the URL field I get all the correct results.

but when I'm using jquery code:

```
$.post(http://localhost:8983/solr/select/?q=body:hello, function(data){
       alert(data);
});
```

OR

```
$.post('http://localhost:8983/solr/select/?, {q: 'body:hello'}, function(data){
       alert(data);
});
```

I get nothing. it doesn't give me anything. not even an alert.

I have tried `$.get` as well without result.

what could the problem be and what is best practice for using solr with ajax?

Comment: is this just a formatting issue here, or are you missing a ' in your real code too?

Comment: i had it removed but it is still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [$.getJSON](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.getJSON) and the [JSON response writer](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolJSON) (wt=json in your querystring).

Also take a look at the [ajax-solr project](http://github.com/evolvingweb/ajax-solr).

Comment: should i use jquery or php to get data from solr? which one is the best solution and why?

Comment: that's a whole other question which you have already posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900474/php-of-jquery-to-access-solr