# php of jquery to access solr?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, solr

im a beginner in using solr.

i know that you can either use ajax solr or solr-php-client to get the search results from solr.

but which should i use or are there occasions you have to choose one of them?

for example, which one is a better solution for autocompletion and which one is better for search content in threads?

would appreciate if someone could shed a light on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use PHP (or another server side language) for essential functionality.
- Use client side JS for optional extras.
- [Build on stuff that works.](http://icant.co.uk/articles/pragmatic-progressive-enhancement/#build)

Answer (score 1):

If you use SolrJS you're exposing your Solr instance to the world, so you need to make sure you disable the update handler. With solr-ajax you can set up a proxy to avoid this.

See [Security concerns](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrJS#Security_concerns) for details, also: http://wiki.github.com/evolvingweb/ajax-solr/comparison-to-solrjs

Answer (score 0):

For auto-completion, AJAX is the only valid option. As for searching threads, either way would be acceptable.

Comment: ajax is **not** the only option for auto-completion. you *can* use a server-side script.

Comment: well if you have to call the server then it is. if you can pre-fetch all the possible suggestions then you can do it without XHR, off course ...

Comment: If you don't put everything client side up front, then Ajax **is** the only way to get the data from said server side script (unless you want to throw in a Flash HTTP object and claim it isn't Ajax)!

Comment: @David: this is about solr-ajax, not about ajax only.